# JavaScript- Stuck on trying to make a 3rd button work with this code

Tags: javascript, arrays, button

I am new to JS and I was given this piece of code to work with. All I need is to add a 3rd button but I am stuck after adding "array7". Any thoughts? I've haven't built a button quite like this-

```
(function () {
    var objDiv = document.getElementById('cas4_ileinner'); //declaring an object and assign it to the element on the page

    if (objDiv) {
        var name = document.getElementById('cas4_ileinner').innerHTML; //declaring an object and assigning the HTML code contained in the element on the page
        var array3 = new Array(); //array to split the hmlt code from the account name
        var array4 = new Array(); //array to split the hmlt code from the account name
        var array5 = //array of guardian account names
        ['Census',];
        var array6 = //array of Smart customers
        ['Jane',];


        array3 = name.split('>'); //splitting the account from the other HTML code
        array4 = String(array3[1]).split('<'); //splitting the account from the other HTML code
        //window.alert(array4);
        var content4 = 'null'

        if (array5.indexOf(array4[0]) > - 1) { //comparing the account name in the account name array to the string split from the HTML element to each other. 
           content4 = name + '<a target="_blank" href="helloworld.com" <span class="btnPrimary" style="color:white; background-color:red" style="margin: 0px 0px 6px 6px; padding-top:4px;">Guardian</span></a>';

           objDiv.innerHTML = content4; //update the element to include a Guardian Account
        }

        if (array6.indexOf(array4[0]) > - 1) {//comparing the account name in the account name array to the string split from the HTML element to each other. 

            if (content4 != 'null'){
                //window.alert(content4);
                var content5 = content4 + '<a target="_blank" href="goodbyeworld.com" <span class="btnPrimary" style="color:black; background-color:yellow" style="margin: 0px 0px 6px 6px; padding-top:4px;">Smart</span></a>';

                objDiv.innerHTML = content5; //update the element to include a Smart case
                // window.alert(content4);
            } else {

                var content5 = name + '<a target="_blank" href="goodbye world.com" <span class="btnPrimary" style="color:black; background-color:yellow" style="margin: 0px 0px 6px 6px; padding-top:4px;">Smart</span></a>';

                objDiv.innerHTML = content5; //update the element to include a Smart case
                                    //window.alert(content5);
            }
        }

    }              
})();
```

Comment: please add the html part as well - only the relevant part.

Comment: And I see no `array7` in your code.